# Terraform Output linux command option?

Tags: terraform, remote-execution

Is there any way I can execute a command on remote machine with Terraform and have the result of that command show me by output?
I can use provisioner(remote-exec) to install and run commands on remote machine but couldn't find a way to the result of the command show me by output.

Thank you for your time guys.

Comment: `remote-exec` shows the stdout of the commands. So what is the actual issue? Do you have any example?

Comment: @Marcin Teacher wants to see the password to be shown at the end of the operation with other outputs. This command sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword will show the password from remote machine but how can I make it show it with outputs at the end of the Terraform apply operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do what you want with [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). You would have to program the external data source to run the commands on the remote host and return what you want return for further processing in your TF code.

Other possibility is to have your `remote-exec` populate an external parameter store (e.g. SSM Parameter Store in AWS), and then once your
`remote-exec` finishes, you would fetch the data from it using [aws_ssm_parameter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ssm_parameter) data source.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I will just SSH to remote machine and run the command myself then I will add that to outputs.

Comment: Of course. Sorry, first time posting here :)

Comment: @Emir No problem. If you encounter new issues, please feel free to make new question.